# Is it possible to get page context within JSTL custom tag doTag()?

Tags: web-applications, jstl, custom-tags

I'm just a beginner and developing my first web-application. I'm trying to make support for several languages, so I use bundle-based messages in the body of my JSTL custom tag logic. Like this:

```
ResourceBundle rs = ResourceBundle.getBundle("i18n.messages");

JspWriter out = getJspContext().getOut();
try {


out.print("<table><thead>");
        out.print("<th>"+ rs.getString("table.id") +"</th>");
        out.print("<th>"+ rs.getString("table.name") +"</th>");
        out.print("<th>"+ rs.getString("table.entry") +"</th>");
        out.print("<th>"+ rs.getString("table.diagnosis") +"</th>");
        out.print("<th>"+ rs.getString("table.doctor") +"</th>");
        out.print("<th>"+ rs.getString("table.release") +"</th>");
        out.print("</thead><tbody>");
```

And the problem is - I couldn't find any possibility to set a Locale for this bundle wihout declaring an excess tag attribute. Kinda:

```
<attribute>
  <name>locale</name>
  <required>true</required>
  <rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
  <type>java.lang.String</type>
</attribute>
```

and then:

```
<table:patients locale="${pageContext.request.locale}" />
```

But it seems to work incorrect, always passing the same locale string (default to my browser???), independently of what I've set in my header with

```
<fmt:setLocale value="${param.locale}" scope="session"/>
```

Is there any smart way to get session context within doTag() body?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

JSTL also provides a Java API that may be of use, but you'll need to implement the `Tag` interface (not `SimpleTag`) because you'll need a way to get at a `PageContext` instance. Assuming you're extending `TagSupport`, try the following:

```
import javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.LocaleSupport;

    public int doEndTag() throws JspException {
        //...
        String tableId = LocaleSupport.getLocalizedMessage(this.pageContext, "table.id", "i18n.messages");
        //...
        return EVAL_PAGE;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access the request, response, session and the other objects in the JSTL custom tag implementation by using the SimpleTagSupport:

```
class MyCustomTag extends SimpleTagSupport {
    @Override
    public void doTag() throws JspException, IOException {
        final PageContext pageContext = (PageContext) getJspContext();
        final ServletRequest request = pageContext.getRequest();
        final ServletResponse response = pageContext.getResponse();
        final HttpSession session = pageContext.getSession();
    }
}
```